# update inner Knockout property dosn't work after cloning the object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, typescript

i have this knockout property

```
public SelectedItem: KnockoutObservable<Student> = ko.observable<Student>();
```

and this is the Studant Class

```
export class Student{
    public Name: KnockoutObservable<string> = ko.observable<string>();
}
```

now i want to update the selected Student name, how to do it?

this are not working

```
public UpdateName()
{
     var self= this;
     self.SelectedItem.Name("new name");
     self.SelectedItem().Name("new name");    
}
```

there is no problem dealing with the SelectedItem as a whole, like **self.SelectedItem(new Student....**

**Update**

found i am cloning the Student object before updating the value what should i do to make the update effect take place [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/16095/)

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Throws an exception? Doesn't change the value? Changes the value to the wrong thing? Opens a new browser window?

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh: Tears a rip in the fabric of space-time? But seriously, a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would help a lot here, even if it's the Javascript produced from the Typescript source.

Comment: Your jsfiddle works just fine if you add jQuery as a reference. http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/16134/

Answer (score 2):

You should never assign an observable like " self.SelectedItem = new Student" That may be your issue. Once you do that, SelectedItem is no longer an observable. You should use self.SelectedItem(new Student());

Your second version of assigning to name is the correct versions: self.SelectedItem().Name("new name");

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the wrong `this`. Try:

```
public UpdateName =()=>
{
     var self= this;
     self.SelectedItem.Name("new name");
     self.SelectedItem().Name("new name");    
}
```

Comment: Thoght its not right to comment here just to draw your attention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23147592/how-to-call-a-function-again-and-again-using-knockout If possible can you please answer it.I will delete this comment after some time I promise