# How to call a function again and again using knockout

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have this knockout code.

```
self.newPatient = ko.asyncCommand({

     execute: function(complete) {
        var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );
        if(isValid){
        var patientJson=ko.toJSON(self.patient());
        formdata.append("json",patientJson);
        //self.enableButton(false);
     var imagepath= $.ajax({
                url: projectUrl+"newPatient", 
                type: "POST",
                data: formdata,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (res) {
                    formdata = new FormData();
                    imagepath=res;
                    var length=self.patients().length;
                    var patient=self.patient();
                //  self.enableButton(true);
                }
     });    


     } 
     },
     canExecute: function(isExecuting) {
         return !isExecuting && isDirty() && isValid();
     }
 });
```

This is my  html inputfields

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Username :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                    <input class="span8" type="text" data-bind="value: username" name="username" data-required="true" data-trigger="change" data-remote="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/isUserNameExists" data-remote-method="GET">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputIcon">Password :</label>
            <div class="controls">
                <div class="input-prepend">
                    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-hand-right"></i></span>
                    <input class="span8" type="password" data-bind="value: password" name="password" data-required="true" data-trigger="change">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and this is my button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary"
                                                    data-bind="command: $root.newPatient, activity: $root.newPatient.isExecuting">
                                                    <i class="icon-ok icon-white"></i> Save
                                                </button>
```

when I press the save button then execute: function(complete){.....} is called and inside this function

```
var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );
```

is called which checks form validity and if the form is invalid then isValid is false and hence the ajax is not called.

I want to call

```
 var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );
        if(isValid){.....}
```

when any of the input field is changed .So can any body please suggest me how to do?

Comment: To start with, you should probably validate the viewmodel instead of the view, if you ask me. Make a computed property which reads and validates all the properties in it's evaluator body. The computed property will alwyas be called when a property is updated.

Comment: @robert.westerlund thanks for your suggestion but my viewmodel consists lot many.So i think it would not be best practice to validate all viewmodel.

Comment: Only validate the properties which you want to validate then. For doing the validation, you could have a look at the [Knockout Validation plugin at the Knockout Contrib github page](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation).

Comment: @robert.westerlund Thanks again but the problem is we are already using parsley.js for validation so they are not allowing me to other plugins.

Comment: Okay, but then your question has really not much to do with knockout. :) In general, it's not a good idea to use the DOM from a viewmodel, since you'll be tying your viewmodel to the view. If you want to listen to changes to the DOM, and since it's seems like you are using jQuery, couldn't you just do `$(':input').change(function(){ /* do the validation */ });`?

Comment: @robert.westerlund if you dont mind I want discuss another issue not related with question.See actually when the page gets loaded for the 1st time,save button is enabled and if I press the save button then control goes to here `execute: function(complete) {
        var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );
        if(isValid){` now I am using jquery to check if any other fields are modified and checking the validation        `var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );` if isValid is true then I am enabling button.Now my question after the button is enabled

Comment: @robert.westerlund and if I click the save button then control is not going to `execute: function(complete) {
      alert(isDirty());
      var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );` can you tell me how to solve?

Comment: If you have another question, please write it as another question on stackoverflow. If you feel it it related to this question you could add a link to that question in the comments here.

Comment: @robert.westerlund I hope you have read it and if you know the answer then I will post this as question.I am not putting this as question because I think this will be put as **too broad**

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `subscribe` function of your observable to run code:

```
username.subscribe(function () { isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' ); }
password.subscribe(function () { isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' ); }
```

**Update after your comment:** 
Here is what I would do:

```
<div id='koRoot'>
    <input type='text' data-bind='value: username' />
    <input type='text' data-bind='enable: enableButton,value: password' />
    <input type='button' data-bind='command: newPatient' value='Go!' />
</div>
...
```

And the js:

```
    var callNewPatient = function () {
        if (self.awaitingValidation()) self.newPatient.execute();
    }

    this.username.subscribe(callNewPatient);
    this.password.subscribe(callNewPatient);

    this.newPatient = ko.asyncCommand({
        execute: function (complete) {
            self.isValid(self.username() === 'me' && self.password() === 'pass');
            if (self.isValid()) {
                self.awaitingValidation(false);
                alert("Valid!");
            } else {
                self.awaitingValidation(true);
            }
        },
        canExecute: function (isExecuting) {
            return self.isValid();
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nyothecat/LkaEJ/1/

Comment: Thanks for answering.when ever I change any field then the canexecute part is executiing.for example I did like this `canExecute: function(isExecuting) { alert('hi');
         return !isExecuting && isDirty() && isValid();
     }` and after that when i when i change one field and press tab button then hi alert comes up

Comment: @JqueryLearner ok, what is the problem you are having then?

Comment: when I press the save button then control goes to execute part.Now suppose if some fields are missed `        var isValid=$('#addPatientForm').parsley( 'validate' );` isvalid is false and hence `if` block is not executed and the save button is in disabled state.Now when I fill the missed fields then I want the save button enable again.This is not happening for me

Comment: can you please provide any idea?

Comment: Thanks again for providing the fiddle but the fiddle does not work if I press go button at the beginning.See I run the fiddle and deleted all the fields then clicked the go button.so the button got disabled.Now I filled in the fields and so the button has to enabled.But this does not happen.Can you please give me a solution for this

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own bindingHandler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.parsley = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings, viewModel, bindingContext) {
        var isValid = valueAccessor();
        var $form = $(element).closest('form');
        $(element).change(function() {
            isValid($form.parsley('validate'));
        });
    }
};
```

And in your ViewModel:

```
self.isValid = ko.observable(false);
```

And then:

```
<form ...>
    <input data-bind="parsley: isValid, ..." />
</form>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/sjroesink/ksqXx/

**Edit**

Without being able to reproduce your error, or an actual line where the error occurs, I cannot help you.
Try using Chrome's Developer tools to see where the error occurs:

[image: track error]

Comment: Thanks for answering but can you please tell me where will i write bindingHandler code.Do I need to write inside `self.newPatient=ko.asyncCommand({......})`

Comment: You can put it anywhere, as long as it's executed before `ko.applyBindings`. In your ViewModel isn't the right place though. I'd just put it right after including knockout.

Comment: I've added a working example at jsfiddle. Can you reproduce your situation in jsfiddle?

Comment: The error occurs because you're missing `ko.DirtyFlag` (KoLite?).

Comment: So how to fix it? Can you please update the fiddle?or else tell me the steps

Comment: You're using code that depends on a third party scripts. `ko.DirtyFlag` and `ko.asyncCommand` are part of https://github.com/CodeSeven/KoLite, which is not included in your fiddle. Also, this has nothing to do with your original question.

Comment: Hi not in the fiddle but in my project also I am getting error.ohh yes In my project knockout.command.js ,knockout.dirtyflag,knockout.validation and knockout.databindings are included.I am new to this field so just completely unaware of it

Comment: See my edit, at the moment I don't have enough information to help you.

Comment: Can i get a solution?

Comment: I tried your solution in my context and it  doesn not work well.
My submit button only appears if the user fill the field => good. I tried to empty the field to see if the parsley require message is throwed and that works as well => good BUT the function i put on the submit binding is called... So the form is sent even if the field is empty